# How to create a level system in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a simple math game that has a set order of 5 questions. I currently only have the first two problems implemented as functions as well as "victory" and "loss" functions that are called based on the player answer. However, I cannot figure out how to make a proper level system. Here is the current code for the four functions I have implemented:

```
def victory():
    global num_correct
    global time

    while True:
        screen.fill((150, 200, 255))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        victory_text = font.render("Correct!", True, dark_blue)

        time -= 1
        timer.tick(100)
        if time <= 0:
            second_problem()

        score_display(30, 25)
        screen.blit(victory_text, (325, 240))
        pygame.display.update()

# when incorrect answer is chosen, call this function 
def loss():
    global num_correct
    global time

    while True:
        screen.fill((150, 200, 255))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        loss_text = font.render("Incorrect!", True, dark_blue)

        time -= 1
        timer.tick(100)
        if time <= 0:
            second_problem()

        score_display(30, 25)
        screen.blit(loss_text, (310, 240))
        pygame.display.update()

# first math problem (9 - 6) + 3 = 6
def first_problem():
    global num_correct

    while True:
        screen.fill((150, 200, 255))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        gametext = font.render("(9 - 6) + 3 = ", True, dark_blue)
        if six.draw(screen):
            print("true")
            num_correct += 1
            victory()

        if eight.draw(screen):
            print("false")
            loss()

        score_display(30, 25)
        screen.blit(gametext, (290, 75))
        pygame.display.update()

# second math problem 3 + (4 * 1) = 7
def second_problem():
    global num_correct

    while True:
        screen.fill((150, 200, 255))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        gametext = font.render("3 + (4 * 1) = ", True, dark_blue)
        if seven.draw(screen):
            print("true")
            num_correct += 1
            victory()

        if nine.draw(screen):
            print("false")
            loss()

        score_display(30, 25)
        screen.blit(gametext, (290, 75))
        pygame.display.update()
```

Currently "victory" and "loss" only advance to the second problem. I plan to implement 5 in total. How can I create a level system of sorts to call upon the problems in a set order?

Comment: A common idiom is a state machine, there are [some](https://github.com/Mekire/pygame-mutiscene-template-with-movie) [examples](https://gist.github.com/iminurnamez/8d51f5b40032f106a847) that might help you.

Comment: What are `seven` and `nine`? You might want to consider a list that contains your problems and their solutions in e.g. dicts, and refactor your code to look at those.

Comment: you can keep problems (function's names) on list. And every problem could return True or False (victory or lose) and use this value to run next problem from list or repeat current problem (or go to the beginning of game)

Comment: you could reduce it to single function which gets parameters `problem("3 + (4 * 1) = ", "7")` , `problem("(9 - 6) + 3 = ", "6")` and then you could run it in some loop which gets  values from list.

Comment: instead of `victory()` and `loss()` you could use one function with different parameters `message("Correct!")` and `message("Incorrect!")`

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce your code. Instead of `first_problem()` and `second_problem()` you could use one function with different values

```
problem("3 + (4 * 1) = ", "7", "9")
problem("(9 - 6) + 3 = ", "6", "9")
```

And function should return `True` or `False` instead of running `victory()` or `loss()`

And then you could keep values on list and use `for`-loop

```
all_problems =  [
    # (question, answer1, answer2)
    ("(9 - 6) + 3 = ", "6", "9"),
    ("3 + (4 * 1) = ", "7", "9"),
]

score = 0

for data in all_problems:
    result = problem(*data)
    if result:
        score += 1
        victory()
    else:
        loss()
        break   # exit when wrong answer
```

You would reduce `victory()` and `loss()` to one function with parameter `message('Corrent!')`, `message('Corrent!')` and then you could do

```
all_problems =  [
    # (question, answer1, answer2)
    ("(9 - 6) + 3 = ", "6", "9"),
    ("3 + (4 * 1) = ", "7", "9"),
]

score = 0

for data in all_problems:
    result = problem(*data)
    if result:
        score += 1
        message('Corrent!')
    else:
        message('Incorrent!')
        break   # exit when wrong answer

# - end -

message(f"Final Result: {score}")
```

---

Full working code with more changes.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

RED   = (255, 0, 0)
GREEM = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE   = (0, 0, 255)

DARK_BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# --- classes ---

class Button:
    
    def __init__(self, answer, correct, x, y):
        self.answer = answer
        self.correct = correct
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(centerx=x, centery=y)
        
        self.text_image = font.render(answer, True, DARK_BLUE)
        self.text_rect  = self.text_image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.text_image, self.text_rect)
    
    def on_mouse_clicked(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            return self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
        
    def on_mouse_motion(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.image.fill(RED)
            else:
                self.image.fill(WHITE)
        
# --- functions ---

def score_display(screen, value, x, y):
    
    text = f'Score: {value}'
    
    text_image = font.render(text, True, DARK_BLUE)
    text_rect  = text_image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)

    screen.blit(text_image, text_rect)

def message(text, time=2):
    
    text_image = font.render(text, True, DARK_BLUE)
    text_rect  = text_image.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = screen.get_rect().center

    screen.fill((150, 200, 255))
    score_display(screen, score, 30, 25)
    screen.blit(text_image, text_rect)
    pygame.display.update()

    time = time * 10
    
    while time >= 0:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return

        time -= 1
        timer.tick(10)  # 20*10 = 2 seconds


def problem(question, answer1, answer2, correct1, correct2):

    centerx, centery = screen.get_rect().center

    text_image = font.render(question, True, DARK_BLUE)
    text_rect  = text_image.get_rect()
    
    text_rect.centerx = centerx
    text_rect.centery = centery - 100
    
    button1 = Button(answer1, correct1, centerx-100, centery+100)
    button2 = Button(answer2, correct2, centerx+100, centery+100)
    
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if button1.on_mouse_clicked(event):
                    return button1.correct
                if button2.on_mouse_clicked(event):
                    return button2.correct
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                button1.on_mouse_motion(event)
                button2.on_mouse_motion(event)
                    
        screen.fill((150, 200, 255))
        score_display(screen, score, 30, 25)
        screen.blit(text_image, text_rect)
        button1.draw(screen)
        button2.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()

        timer.tick(10)

# --- main ---

all_problems =  [
    # (question, answer1, answer2, correct1, correct2)
    ("(9 - 6) + 3 = ", "6", "9", True, False),
    ("3 + (4 * 1) = ", "7", "9", True, False),
]

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)

timer = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0

for data in all_problems:
    result = problem(*data)
    if result:
        score += 1
        message('Corrent!')
    else:
        message('Incorrent!')
        break

message(f"Final Result: {score}")
pygame.quit()
```

[image]

[image]